# Install custom TeX packages

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, quarto, tinytex

I'm trying to install a custom Latex package ([this Beamer template](https://github.com/TOB-KNPOB/Beamer-LaTeX-Themes/tree/main/SZU%20Presentation)). I've tried to create a new directory under `...\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\texmf-local\`, copy the .sty files and refresh Tinytex with `tlmgr update --self -all` `tlmgr path add` `fmtutil-sys --all`, but when I call `pksewhich mypackage.sty` it still doesn't shows.

Comment: The easiest way to install custom packages is to put them in home texmf tree, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1138/36296

Comment: Exactly what I did and didn't work

Comment: You put it in your texmf tree, not the home texmf tree.

Comment: What does `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME` say?

Comment: C:/Users/alber/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-local

Comment: Ok, strange setup, but might be what tinytex does. Did you place your files in `C:/Users/alber/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-local/tex/latex/`?

Comment: At first I tried to create a folder under temxf-local. Then, I've tried under texmf-local/tex/latex and also didn't work. I might just drop Tinytex and go for MikTex instead

Comment: If you are looking for a new distribution, I'd go with texlive. This the most widely used distro and thus best tested. Miktex has a lot of packaging errors recently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue [Install package manually #377](https://github.com/rstudio/tinytex/issues/377) on TinyTeX github repo describes a way to do this.

Steps are

1. Create a `texmf` folder

   ```
   mkdir ~/texmf
   ```
2. Then create TeX directory structure

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/texmf/tex/latex
   ```
3. Then put the custom-latex-package folder  under `~/texmf/tex/latex` directory
4. Then Add to TeX's "search PATH"

   ```
   tlmgr conf auxtrees add ~/texmf
   ```

Then `kpsewhich beamerthemesintef.sty` returns

```
c:/Users/User/texmf/tex/latex/custom_pkg/beamerthemesintef.sty
```

and one caveat of this approach as [@Yihui pointed out](https://github.com/rstudio/tinytex/issues/377#issuecomment-1166182123) is that, you need to repeat the 4th step after upgrading or reinstalling `TinyTeX`.