# Quarto `Knit` failing with pdf

Tags: r, rstudio, quarto

I try to knit a pdf document using `quarto` and receive the following error:

> compilation failed- package installation error
> I can't find file `pgfkeyslibraryfiltered.code.tex'.
> l.1230 \input pgfkeyslibraryfiltered.code.tex

The file is located at `~library/tinytex/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeyslibraryfiltered.code.tex` with all the other docs.

I've tried downloading Rstudio and tinytex to no avail. Any advice?

I'm working on a Mac with an M1 chip.

Comment: does .rmd work?

Comment: Running `quarto check` in the terminal might be a helpful troubleshooting step.  If the quarto installation isn't on your system path, then you can can determine the installation path of quarto from R using `quarto::quarto_path()` function and test that specific binary defining the path specifically - i.e. `/usr/local/bin/quarto check`

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74921834/10858321) may be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: re-install tinytex. Don't just re-download the package! You have to do `tinytex::install_tinytex()`. Then everything works great!